# PIG: Multiple records to be arranged in particular set of columns

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I've a scenario where I have data as below:

```
Customer ID | Customer Name | Customer Post Code |Relation
C1 | John | E6 1NQ | R1
C2 | Peter | WC2 8AD | R1
C3 | Emilia | PC81 7RE | R1
C4 | Jessica | NE24 5RE | R1
```

I've to process the above data using PIG and prepare the extract as below:

```
Relation | Customer ID | Customer Name | Customer Post Code | Customer ID | Customer Name | Customer Post Code
R1 | C1 | John | E6 1NQ | C2 | Peter | WC2 8AD
R1 | C3 | Emilia | PC81 7RE | C4 | Jessica | NE24 5RE
```

I've tried group by on the input table on R1 and then tried to create columns using FOREACH but it didn't helped me.

Comment: Can you include your Pig code, please?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by first grouping the records by RELATION then used enumerate to rank the grouped records.
After this I created two relations, first relation with records having odd number ranks and second relation with records having even number ranks.
After this I did FULL OUTER JOIN BY RELATION and Rank on both relation followed by generation of desired output